How to specify Decimal precision in Python before uploading to Redshift?
I have a Redshift table schema defined like so:
   id: string
   col 1: decimal(17,12)
   col 2: decimal(20,2)
   col 3: decimal(4,2)

I have a python dataframe that I will convert into a parquet file that I need to modify to fit these specifics.
  id         col1          col2            col3
  1      1000.234234     00.92342      13424534.34234
  2      23434234.23     01.234        13424534.34234
  3      98764.23        00.56789      13424534.34234
  4      2352352.2233    23423.323     13424534.34234
  5      102342.34       23.123123     13424534.34234

I am using the following to create the decimal type but trying to figure out who to get it to the exact numbers for each column dynamically:
data[col].astype(str).apply(Decimal)

but it is returning values like:
   id: string
   col 1: decimal(4,2)
   col 2: decimal(13,2)
   col 3: decimal(4,2)

How can I specify the exact precision so it matches the defined schema?
